# Cookies in ASP.NET Core rc2

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

Can someone pls explain how to store and get cookies in an ASP.NET Core rc2 application? I can only find outdated information about the old `HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Get` and `Add` methods, neither of which still exist in Core. Also, the `HttpCookie` class doesn't seem to exist either.

What is the new cookie class and how can I get and add one?

(Note: I am not specifically taking about authentication cookies, just general data cookies)

Comment: Have you tried Append (as per https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/3a97a6bdfdcc3787bf4b68cecdf277588de5ee76/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features/IResponseCookies.cs)?

Comment: See https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/ChunkingCookieManager.cs The class has methods for getting request cookie and setting response cookie

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For getting request cookie value:

```
HttpContext.Request.Cookies["<key>"]
```

Setting response cookie:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("<key>", <value>, <options?>)
```