# Create cookie with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET MVC 5 I had the following extension:

```cs
public static ActionResult Alert(this ActionResult result, String text) {
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("alert") { Path = "/", Value = text };
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    return result;
}
```

Basically I am adding a cookie with a text.

In ASP.NET Core I can't find a way to create the `HttpCookie`. Is this no longer possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cookies in ASP.NET Core rc2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958343/cookies-in-asp-net-core-rc2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cookies and ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166075/cookies-and-asp-net-core)

Comment: If you need to support multiple values per cookie, you can check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701126/how-to-handle-multi-value-cookies-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
    public static ActionResult Alert(this ActionResult result, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResponse response, string text)
    {
        response.Cookies.Append(
            "alert",
            text,
            new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions()
            {
                Path = "/"
            }
        );

        return result;
    }
```

You may also have to pass the Response in your call to the extension method from the controller (or wherever you call it from).  For example:

```
return Ok().Alert(Response, "Hi");
```

[StackOverflow Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166075/cookies-asp-net-core)