# How to handle multi value cookies in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core

In the full .NET framework we have support for multi value cookies. e.g. a cookie could have multiple values:

```
HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("userInfo");
aCookie.Values["userName"] = "patrick";
aCookie.Values["lastVisit"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

See also [the docs about `HttpCookie.Values` on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.values%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [ASP.NET Cookies Overview on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

With ASP.NET Core, the multi value cookie seems to be gone. There is no `HttpCookie.Values` and [`HttpRequest.Cookies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequest_Cookies) returns a [`IRequestCookieCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.irequestcookiecollection#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_IRequestCookieCollection) which is like a  `dictionary` from `string` to `string`

How should I now create and read multi value cookies in ASP.NET Core? How could I read the multi value cookies created in Full ASP.NET and read them in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Have you tried reading a "legacy" cookie? That might give some insight. A legacy NameValueCollection could be serialized to/from string pretty straightforwardly. It would be interesting to find out why the legacy multi value cookie is not natively supported by core.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I believe that ASP.NET Core removed the support for the old legacy multi-value cookies because this feature was never standardized.

The [RFC definition for cookies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) explicitly states that using the `Set-Cookie` header you can assign a single name/value pair, with optionally metadata associated.

The official implementation of `Values` property for .NET `HttpCookie` is very brittle, and just serializes/deserializes key-value pairs to/from a string with separators `&` for pairs and `=` for values.

Mocking this behavior in ASP.NET core should be fairly easy, you could use extension methods to handle those legacy formatted cookies:

```
public static class LegacyCookieExtensions
{
    public static IDictionary<string, string> FromLegacyCookieString(this string legacyCookie)
    {
        return legacyCookie.Split('&').Select(s => s.Split('=')).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp[0], kvp => kvp[1]);
    }

    public static string ToLegacyCookieString(this IDictionary<string, string> dict)
    {
        return string.Join("&", dict.Select(kvp => string.Join("=", kvp.Key, kvp.Value)));
    }
}
```

Using them like this:

```
// read the cookie
var legacyCookie = Request.Cookies["userInfo"].FromLegacyCookieString();
var username = legacyCookie["userName"];

// write the cookie
var kvpCookie = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "userName", "patrick" },
    { "lastVisit", DateTime.Now.ToString() }
};
Response.Cookies.Append("userInfo", kvpCookie.ToLegacyCookieString());
```

*Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7KrJ5S*

If you need a more complex serialization/deserialization logic (which handles formatting errors and escapes characters in cookie values) you should look and grab some code from the [Mono HttpCookie implementation](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpCookie.cs), which, I believe, is a little more robust.

Comment: How do you integrate the Mono HttpCookie implementation in a living ASP.NET Core system?

Comment: Note that ASP.NET Core will encode your special characters such as = in the cookie value. So you if you need interoperability with legacy applications, you need to look for solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48324815

Answer (score 4):

**CookieManager** wrapper allows you to play with objects. you can easily read/write object in asp.net core. it offers you to encrypt the cookie value to secure your data

check out: https://github.com/nemi-chand/CookieManager

Create your poco/object what you want to store in cookie.

```
public class MyCookie
{
  public string Id { get; set; }

  public DateTime Date { get; set; }

  public string Indentifier { get; set; }
}
```

fill the object values

```
MyCookie cooObj= new MyCookie()
{
  Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
  Indentifier = "valueasgrsdgdf66514sdfgsd51d65s31g5dsg1rs5dg",
  Date = DateTime.Now
};
```

set the myCookie object

```
_cookieManager.Set("Key", cooObj, 60);
```

get the myCookie object

```
MyCookie objFromCookie = _cookieManager.Get<MyCookie>("Key");
```