# Creating a custom cookie with a custom name in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

In ASP.NET Framework, it was possible to define a custom cookie with a custom name in the constructor, like this:

```
HttpCookie customCookie = new HttpCookie("name");
customCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
customCookie["key"] = "value";
context.Response.Cookies.Add(customCookie);
```

In ASP.NET Core, the approach has changed to something more like this:

```
CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions();
cookieOptions.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
context.Response.Cookies.Append("key", "value", cookieOptions);
```

There seems to be no way to set the "name" of the cookie as there is no option defined in the [CookieOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookieoptions?view=aspnetcore-3.1) class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ASP.NET - multi-value cookies compatibility**

The line

```
customCookie["key"] = "value";
```

is a shortcut to the `Values` property. It is equivalent to

```
customCookie.Values["key"] = "value";
```

This property allows the use of multi-value cookies and is provided for compatibility with previous versions of Active Server Pages (ASP).

**ASP.NET Core cookie - no built in compatibility for multi-value cookies**

ASP.NET Core removed the support for the old legacy multi-value cookies because this feature was never standardized. More information why it is not supported is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701126/how-to-handle-multi-value-cookies-in-asp-net-core). The link also has a nice extention for multi-value cookies in ASP.NET Core.

This line

```
context.Response.Cookies.Append("key", "value", cookieOptions);
```

adds a cookie to the HTTP response and sets the name of the new cookie to "key" and its value to "value".

Comment: I was able to solve my usage case by serializing a Dictionary<string, string> using JSON.NET. Thanks!